# JQuery - trigger hover over separate element

Tags: jquery, hover

Simple question - how do I make an element appear to be hovered when I trigger it from another element?

Example jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/391305/

Body:

```
<span class="itemA"></span>
<button>
TriggerAHover
</button>
```

Js:

```
   $(document).ready(function(){
    $('button').on("click", function(){
      $('.itemA').trigger('mouseover');
    })
    });
```

Css:

```
   .itemA {
     display:block;
            background: blue;
            width: 40px;
            height: 40px;
        }

        .itemA:hover {
            background: red;
        }
```

This fiddle creates a blue background span.  On hover, the span changes red.
I want the span to also change to a hovered state on click of the button.  I've tried .trigger('mouseover'), .trigger('mouseenter'), and .trigger('hover'), but they do not change the span element to its hovered state.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

mouseover or mouseenter will just trigger .on("mouseenter") or .on("mouseover") functions.
css hover is only activated by the pointer

Why dont you just add a class on click that has the same style as :hover?

Comment: I know I can add a class, I first wanted to see if my question was possible before working around it.  Seeing as it doesn't seem possible now, I will end up doing it the way you stated, thank you

Answer (score 0):

Like what Jorgedl said I think it would be better to switch the class.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('button').click(function() {
     $('.itemA').toggleClass('itemA hovered');
  });
});
```

CSS:

```
  .hovered {
        display:block;
        background: red;
        width: 40px;
        height: 40px;
    }
```